# Selenium test tryingnto use firefox instead of chrome

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have the following in my selenium-webdriver test (the test is written as coffee-script):

```
@driver = new selenium.Builder()
    .withCapabilities(selenium.Capabilities.chrome())
    .build()
```

Yet when I run this test the error I get is:
*Error: Failed to install profile; firefox terminated with Result(code=-1073
741819, signal=null)*

I am perplexed why its trying to start firefox (there is no reference to firefox in my code). Also, at one point this was working. I am not sure what changed in my laptop which has resulted in this behavior.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: please provide more of your source-code

Comment: did you install chromedriver? like this "npm install --save chromedriver@2.12.0"

Comment: Yup installed chromedriver exactly as mentioned.

Comment: No worries - I figured the issue - the environment variable SELENIUM_BROWSER was set to firefox.